# What is the difference between Tor and Tails

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, tails

This is kind of a noob question but I would appreciate some response nevertheless. I have been reading a lot about Tor and Tails recently but I am still confused on what does what and the difference between both of them, so I would like to know what the difference is between TOR and TAILS.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in simple terms, [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) (or The Onion Router) is free software that enables anonymous communication on the internet. Tor helps you protect your online privacy and helps you defend against network surveillance and traffic analysis. it prevents somebody watching your Internet connection from learning what sites you visit, and it prevents the sites you visit from learning your physical location. Tor achieves this by directing Internet traffic through free, worldwide, distributed servers which are run by volunteers.

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/about/index.en.html) on the other hand is a full-blown Debian-based operating system that comes with several built-in applications pre-configured with security in mind: web browser, instant messaging client, email client, office suite, image and sound editor, etc. It is designed to be used from a DVD, USB stick, or SD card independently of the computer's original operating system, and it leaves no trace on the computer you are using unless you ask it explicitly. Have a look [here](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/features/index.en.html) to know the full list of features and included software. Tails relies on the Tor anonymity network to protect your privacy online:

- all software is configured to connect to the Internet through Tor
- if an application tries to connect to the Internet directly, the connection is automatically blocked for security.

If you have read this much, there are [few things you can do now](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en):

- Please [consider running a relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en) to help the Tor network grow.
- Tell your friends! Get them to run relays. Get them to run hidden services. Get them to tell their friends.
- If you like [Tor's goals](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en), please take a moment to [donate to support](https://www.torproject.org/donate/donate.html.en) further Tor development.

Answer (score 0):

Tor (not TOR) is like your router at home. To get to the internet, you connect to your router. Tails is an operating system, like Windows. The interaction between Tor and Tails is that Tails is configured to use Tor by default.